# UACCESS not working for /dev/dri/renderD128

Tags: systemd, udev

I have a Raspberry Pi 4/Raspbian and am now attempting to open `/dev/dri/renderD128` for talking to V3D DRM. This fails with `EACCESS`.

Looking into the filesystem:

```
$ ls -l /dev/dri/renderD128 
crw-rw---- 1 root render 226, 128 Aug  1 23:17 /dev/dri/renderD128
$ groups
pi adm dialout cdrom sudo audio video plugdev games users input netdev gpio i2c spi
```

This seems correct, since `pi` is not a user of `render`.

Reading up on this it seems that I should magically (this seems largely undocumented) get access to `renderD128` through a mechanism called *UACCESS*.

The rules contain:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="drm", KERNEL=="renderD*", TAG+="uaccess"
```

so I assume, this should be configured correctly!?

Could anyone explain how this should work or how I can further debug that *UACCESS* mechanism?

Comment: It's different because whoever made your RaspPi distribution (you didn't tell us which one you were using) decided to make it this way. Any reason you can't make `pi` a member of the group `render`?

Comment: Sorry, added the Raspbian. It feels weird to add `pi` to group `render`, when it isn't in the list of default groups for users. Still wondering, what the philosophy around this `render` group is.

Comment: Found some more details: https://salsa.debian.org/systemd-team/systemd/commit/e3772a013721083a740ab9dedbf060cf5b3c3709

Comment: Ah, it's systemd, so you should use their "uaccess" method (however this works, I haven't used it myself) if you don't what to add a user to a group. (And there's nothing strange in adding users to groups, it's a very basic sysadmin operation).